# How to add Maven Bundle to Eclipse OSGi run configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, osgi, equinox

I am developing OSGi bundles for an application.
And to test it, I am able to run the full application from Eclipse.
I set the working directory to a folder that contains a JRE and also a folder with plugins (bundles) that make up the core software I'm running.

Then when I go to run configurations in Eclipse, it shows any bundles I've made as well as the bundles under a "Target Platform" section.

All of this is **without** Maven.

The OSGi framework being used is equinox. And I can see the command being executed by Eclipse basically points to the equinox jar and a config file with all the locations and directories in it etc.

Now what I want to do, is add a bundle I made using Maven.
But the Maven bundle does not show up in the run configuration as an available Bundle.

I suspect it's because the manifest.mf file doesn't exist for the maven project.
It gets generated by the maven build.

If I manually copy the maven built artifact into my running osgi's bundles folder it is picked up and included and works, but that's quite a manual process.

Is there a way to get Eclipse to include the Maven bundles in my **non-maven** OSGi run configuration?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand a thing but using a an non OSGi in a usual project is just done by defining it as a dependency... I don't understand the point of "run configuration"? Running from command line or as a test?

Comment: The target platform that is used by an _OSGi Framework_ run configuration can be configured in the preferences _Plug-in Development > Target Platform_. You can also create a new _Target Definition_ file. If its content change, it has to be reloaded. This can be done in the preferences _Plug-in Development > Target Platform_ by hitting the _Reload_ button.

Comment: khmarbaise, the OSGi project is not not a maven project and doesn't have a pom file or dependencies. I want to add a bundle that is a maven project. The run configuration is how I run the application from Eclipse